# Easier / better way to convert hexadecimal string to list of numbers in Python?

Tags: python, hex

My goal is to  get a 64 characters long hex number from a user (which represent a serial number) and convert to c_type 32bytes number.
Serial Number is defined like this:

```
_sn =  c_ubyte * 32
```

I accept SN string from user into args.sn variable. Here's how I managed to solve it. I'm sure there is an easier and more elegant way, would appreciate your help.

```
SN_List= []
for i in range(0,len(args.sn),2):
    myByte = args.sn[i: i+2]
    num = int("0x" + myByte,16)
    SN_List.append(num)

if(len(SN_List) != 32):
    print("S/N is not valid, it should be 64 hex characters long")
    return 1
_sn = (c_ubyte * 32)(*SN_List)
```

Comment: Have you tried `binascii.a2b_hex`?

Comment: As a side note, you don't need both the `"0x" +` and the `, 16`; one or the other will do.

Answer (score 4):

The very easy way, using [`binascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) (Python 3):

```
import binascii

print(list(binascii.unhexlify(args.sn)))
```

Example:

```
>>> list(binascii.unhexlify('09F911029D74E35BD84156C5635688C0'))
[9, 249, 17, 2, 157, 116, 227, 91, 216, 65, 86, 197, 99, 86, 136, 192]
```

---

In Python 2, you would use

```
print map(ord, args.sn.decode('hex'))
```

Example:

```
>>> sn = '09F911029D74E35BD84156C5635688C0'
>>> print map(ord, sn.decode('hex'))
[9, 249, 17, 2, 157, 116, 227, 91, 216, 65, 86, 197, 99, 86, 136, 192]
```

Comment: It should be almost as easy in Python 2, just with `map(ord, …)`) instead of `list(…)`.

Comment: In Python 2, it's actually slightly easier because of `.decode('hex')`. I amended my answer.

Comment: I never found `decode('hex')` to be any simpler than `unhexlify`. But if you really like that, you can use `codecs.decode(args.sn, 'hex')`, which works in 2.x and 3.3+.

Comment: @abarnert: I always liked it because it let me skip an import - this is important to me when doing short little things on the command-line.

Comment: @nneonneo: Yeah, I occasionally catch myself using `__import__` on python -c command lines just so I can cram the whole expression in with no spaces and avoid quoting my quotes; not having to import anything certainly solves that problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @nneonneo's comment ([`binascii.unhexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) is equivelent to `binascii.a2b_hex`):

```
_sn = (c_ubyte * 32)(*binascii.unhexlify("ffaabb"))
```

Example (with the hex `ffaabb`):

```
>>> binascii.unhexlify("ffaabb")
b'\xff\xaa\xbb'
>>> _sn = (c_ubyte * 32)(*binascii.unhexlify("ffaabb"))
>>> _sn
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_32 object at 0x7fe14fee8bf8>
>>> for i in _sn:
...     print(i)
... 
255
170
187
0
0
<27 more zeros>
```

Comment: that gives what the question asks for (a byte array) in the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use a list comprehension to eliminate most of the overhead code. Second, it's not necessary to prepend `0x` to the string when you convert to int, as long as you've specified the second parameter. Third, if you need to validate the string to make sure it contains the correct number of digits, that should be a separate step. Or perhaps you can just rely on a raised exception when things go wrong.

```
SN_List = [int(args.sn[i: i+2], 16) for i in range(0, 64, 2)]
```