# Convert a hexadecimal string into list of integers

Tags: flutter, dart

Similar to this question here but for flutter/dart: [Easier / better way to convert hexadecimal string to list of numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082596/easier-better-way-to-convert-hexadecimal-string-to-list-of-numbers-in-python)

I have a string with hexadecimal value like `09F911029D74E35BD84156C5635688C0` and I want to return `[9, 249, 17, 2, 157, 116, 227, 91, 216, 65, 86, 197, 99, 86, 136, 192]`. In python I can just use `list(binascii.unhexlify('09F911029D74E35BD84156C5635688C0'))`. Is there such a function for flutter/dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Package **[convert](https://pub.dev/packages/convert/install)** to decode or encode your hex values into desired values

```
var hex = 09F911029D74E35BD84156C5635688C0;
var result = hex.decode(hex);
```

also `import 'package:convert/convert.dart';`

let me know if this works .

Comment: Thanks, that was actually so obvious that I did not even try it. Not sure though what you mean by initializing the HexDecoder first. For me it work by jus using `hex.decode('09F911029D74E35BD84156C5635688C0');`

Comment: its alright , i thought u would be using dartpad for some process (hex is used for encryption and cryptography) , it should work without initialising , i will edit the answer .